# ffmpeg usb Web cam recording terminates randomly before set duration

Tags: ffmpeg

The output of this script is just fine; it's pretty much what I want. But it seems to terminate randomly. My next step will be to try this on another computer to see if the issue persists.

My configuration:
Dell Precision laptop, m4400
2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8600 @ 2.40GHz
Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-116-generic (x86_64)
Card: NVIDIA G96GLM [Quadro FX 770M]
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
USB Camera-B4.09.24.1 Sony Playstation Eye

And this is the script that I'm running - the last time it recorded for about three hours and forty-five minutes, before that it was about 55 minutes; once it ran five and a half hours:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "This is a shell script to make a timelapse video."  
ffmpeg \
-f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -video_size 640x480 -framerate 5 -t 09:00:00 -i /dev/video0 \
-vf "select=not(mod(n\,5)),setpts=N/(60*TB),fps=60, drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%T}':x=20:y=20:fontcolor=white" \
-c:v libx264 -preset superfast -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv422p -g 15 -keyint_min 15 \
-f mpegts /media/dkm/OneTB/Video/Timelapse_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S).ts
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Run with `-vvv` and see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Overnight, I ran this script on three other computers, one of which was run with crontab, and it worked fine on all all three, so I have to conclude that it's outside the mandate of Stackflow and probably a configuration issue. I thought that I might just delete the post, but the code does work, so I offer it up for what it's worth. Hope I'm with the boundaries of etiquette by handling it this way. Thanks to those who had a looksee.